# How to specify minbucket in caret train for?

Tags: r, r-caret, rpart

For CART model, caret seems to only provide tunning of complexity parameter. Is there way to tune other parameters such as minbucket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Arguments passed to the classification or regression routines are included in the dots parameter.

As you want to include `minbucket`, parameter `control` should be included inside `train`.

As example:

```
library("caret")

train(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start, data = kyphosis, 
      method = "rpart",
      tuneGrid = data.frame(cp = c(0.01, 0.05)),
      control = rpart.control(minsplit = 10, minbucket = 5))
```

If you want to tune `minbucket` you will have to do it manually.